# how to access sklearn column transformer within a custom transformer

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have a column transformer that is using  a custom transformer.
My X_train is a numpy array instaead of DataFrame.
The list below are the indices that I want to use on my Numpy array

```
            lst_all_cols = dtprcs.X_train.columns.values.tolist()
            lst_all_idxs = [idx for idx,_ in enumerate(lst_all_cols)]
            lst_signchng_cols = 
            [lst_all_cols.index("DAYS_INSTALMENT"),lst_all_cols.index("DAYS_ENTRY_PAYMENT")]
```

The following is my definition for column transformer

```
            instpmt_preprcs_pipln = ColumnTransformer( transformers = [
                                                    ( 'instpmt_repl_pipln', Xfrmer_replacenp(),lst_all_idxs ),
                                                    ( 'instpmt_sgnchng_pipln', Xfrmer_signchngnp(),lst_signchng_cols )],
                                                    remainder='passthrough')
```

The code below is the custom transformer

```
class Xfrmer_signchngnp(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """
        this transformer does the change for positive to negative 
    """
    # constructor
    def __init__(self):
        #we are not going to use this         
        self.signchng_columns = None
        
    #Return self 
    def fit(self,X,y=None  ):
        return self
    
    def transform(self,X,y=None):        
        #change the sign of the columns
        for col in column:
            print('sign change np')
            X[col]= [0  if val >= 0 else (val *-1) for val in X[col] ]
    
        return X
```

In the column transformer we define three items in the tuple. The name of the transformer, the custom transformers signature and the third parameter as index.
Within the custom transformers fit() or transform() we can access the numpy array as X.
To access the numpy array we need indices which is the third parameter.

**My Question**
How does the third parameter of column transformer get passed to the custom transformer ? so that it can be used to access/process the numpy array selectively.

I tried columns,column,cols but keep getting Name error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns specification **is not** passed to the transformer.  Instead, the `ColumnTransformer` slices the input array down to the specified columns, and passes the smaller array to the transformer.  So your custom transformer should operate on all of the columns it receives.